# How to check whether the sum exists for a given path in a tree

Tags: python, data-structures, binary-tree

I want to check if the sum of values in any path from the start node to the

leaf node exists.

For example suppose I have startNode is say a 7 and the sumTarget is 15 if the tree is:

```
        a-7
  b - 1    e- 8
  c - 2    
  d -9
```

Then since 7 +8 equals 15 it would return true

If I have b as the startNode and 12 as the sumTotal then it would also return true because 1 +2 + 9 is 12 starting with b.

```
class Node {
    int value;
    Node [] children
}
```

I don't think this is right, but I'm not sure what is wrong.

```
def doesSumExist(startNode, sumTarget, currentSum):
    totalSum = sumTarget
    if startNode is not Null:
        if totalSum + startNode.value == sumTarget:
            return True
        else:
            totalSum += startNode.value
    else:
        Node startNode = doesSumExist(startNode.left, sumTarget, currentSum)  
        if startNode is not Null:
            return currentSum
        startNode = doesSumExist(startNode.right, sumTarget,currentSum)
    return False
```

Comment: What is startNode.left and startNode.right? children?
You are not checking the return value of your recursive call. 
You need to pass the argument currentSum instead of erasing sumTarget every time.
You don't want to check if totalSum == startNode.value. You want to check if totalSum+startNode.value == sumTarget.
You don't want to assign totalSum = sumTarget. You want to pass an argument (as I said previously) called currentSum. You need 3 arguments for this recursive function.

If you explain me the structure you're using I will be able to better help you.

Comment: Yes startNode.left and startNode.right are children. I edited the post to include a sample tree and numbers and I also modified the code according to your suggestions. Thanks for your help. Should in the else: totalSum += startNode.value be instead totalSum+= startNode.left or startNode.right?

Answer (score 1):

assuming that your node class looks something like this:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value = 0, children = None):
        self.value = value
        self.children = [] if children is None else children
```

then this method should do the trick:

```
def doesSumExist(startNode, targetSum, currentSum):
    if startNode is None:
        return False
    currentSum += startNode.value
    if currentSum == targetSum:
        return True
    for child in startNode.children:
        if doesSumExist(child, targetSum, currentSum):
            return True
    return False
```

Note that for this Node-class design the None-check of startNode isn't really necessary for the recursion but only for the entry point. So this would probably be better:

```
def doesSumExist(startNode, targetSum):
    def inner(node, targetSum, currentSum):
        currentSum += node.value
        if currentSum == targetSum:
            return True
        #for people who like to save a few lines
        #return any(inner(child, targetSum, currentSum) for child in node.children)
        for child in node.children:
            if inner(child, targetSum, currentSum):
                return True
        return False

    if startNode is None:
        return False
    return inner(startNode, targetSum, 0)
```

Edit:
If you not only want to know if the sum exists in a path from your start node but also if it would exist in any given sub path this should work:

```
def doesSumExist(startNode, targetSum):
    def inner(node, targetSum, allValues):
        allValues.append(node.value)
        currentSum = 0
        for val in reversed(allValues):
            currentSum += val
            if currentSum == targetSum:
                return True
        for child in node.children:
            if inner(child, targetSum, allValues):
                return True
        allValues.pop()
        return False

    if startNode is None:
        return False
    return inner(startNode, targetSum, [])
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this out!

Comment: you're welcome, hope it helps. However this also won't work for finding sums in sub paths as mentioned below. I edited my post with another version that should work for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

In that case I think what you're searching for is something like the following:

```
def doesSumExist(startNode, sumTarget, currentSum):
    totalSum = currentSum
    if startNode is not Null:
        if totalSum + startNode.value == sumTarget: #If this node completes the sum
            return True
        else: #if not
            totalSum += startNode.value #increase current sum
    if doesSumExist(startNode.left, sumTarget, totalSum): #recursive starting on the left children
        return True
    elif doesSumExist(startNode.right, sumTarget, totalSum): #recursive starting on the right children
        return True           
    return False #if the sum is not present (starting in startNode).
```

However, this does not check if any successive combination of nodes contains the sum (the code would much more complex).

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. Yes I am really trying to see if not only say two nodes but also three nodes or more as you said contains the sum. I will work on it more on my own to get it working. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The code I placed will work for any given number of successive nodes. However, if you have the sum within the tree but it does not exist if you start in startNode, it will not find it. 

Imagine your tree, if you do doesSumExist(a, 12, 0) it will not find it because the sum starts in b, not a. Understand?

Comment: In the case where it starts in b it would be (b, 12, 0) I am going to modify the code to get that case working as well. But it might take me several attempts to do so. But I will post back once I get further. Thanks again!

Comment: If it starts in b it will also find it, I think I'm not correctly explaining myself. It finds any existing sum in a path considering it will always start in startNode (whatever the node you're passing to the function). However, if the sum exists in the tree but it starts further down it will not be verified. 
With your example the tree contains the sum 12 if you start in b. But if you call the function doesSumExist(a, 12, 0) it will say it does not because it will contain the value 9 from a.